# How can I stop ConvertTo-HTML from creating an empty table?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am trying to create a report using PowerShell `ConvertTo-HTML`

```
if($FileLine){
    $frag1 = $FileLine | Sort-Object Name  | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment -Property Name,Action -PreContent “<h3>Group Sync : $gcount change(s)</h3>” | Out-String
}else{
    $frag1 = "<h3>Group Sync : $gcount change(s)</h3>There is no change on any group."
}
if($FileLine2){
    $frag2 = $FileLine2 | Sort-Object Name | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment -Property Name,Action,AddedGroups,DeletedGroups -PreContent “<h3>User Sync : $ucount change(s)</h3>” |Out-String
}else{
    $frag2 = "<h3>User Sync : $ucount change(s)</h3>There is no change on any user."
}

#1st try
ConvertTo-Html -head $head -PostContent $frag1,$frag2 -PreContent "<!--empty-->" -body "<BR>" | Out-File $emailfile
#2nd try
#ConvertTo-HTML -body "$frag1 $frag2" -PostContent "<BR>nothing" -head $head | Out-File $emailfile
```

However this code resulting an empty table in my HTML.

[image: Image showing empty table tags]

Any idea why this issue happens? I have tried multiple ways to remove this(sample "2nd try") but it will create the empty table in other place.

Or is there a way to remove this empty table after ConvertTo-HTML being called? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You are currently using the `ConvertTo-HTML` two times. What if you take out the `ConvertTo-HTML` in the IF statements and only do it in your final result?

Comment: I am creating 2 HTML fragments, to be combined into 1 HTML document. In the result. if frag1 and frag2 exists, in the doc 3 tables ( 1 empty 2 populated ) appear.

Comment: The empty table can be the result of converting a `$null` object into html or of selecting properties in the `ConvertTo-Html` cmdlet that do not exist in the input object. Do you have an object in  `$FileLine` that does not have the properties `Name` and `Action`?

Comment: No, even if $FileLine is empty, the extra table still appears.

Comment: What version of PowerShell are you running this from?

Comment: 2.1... For workaround I have put "table:last-child { display: none; visibility: hidden; }" However the empty table still shown in Outlook, so need a permanent solution here. Also reported by people, but since I need the 2 fragments, the solution described here https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/3b4d8fc6-e491-42fe-9a97-a103987203cf/strange-extra-empty-table-when-building-a-report-with-converttohtml?forum=winserverpowershell does not work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know what your main issue is but the solution might be something you need to figure out for yourself. Reading the description of [`ConvertTo-HTML` on TechNet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.0/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-html)

> The ConvertTo-Html cmdlet converts .NET Framework objects into HTML that can be displayed in a Web browser. You can use this cmdlet to display the output of a command in a Web page.

In your final call (in both trys) you are not specifying an `-InputObject` which is what would typically be used as the content for your empty table. Seeing as it is optional this is not an error but the cmdlet created the placeholder table anyway. You don't see this with you `$frag`s because you provided objects via the pipeline.

I tried adding in some dummy/empty data for testing but it obviously did not accomplish anything since I was always adding something.

If you are willing to use some regex you can scrub out the empty table.

```
(ConvertTo-Html | Out-String) -replace "(?sm)<table>\s+</table>"
```

Beyond that, short of building your own HTML content, I do not know how to avoid this.